# Traducción de "triage"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-médico

¿Existe alguna traducción aceptada de este término francés/inglés al español?

No sólo en su sentido médico, sino en el general, aplicado por ejemplo a bugs de software.

Comment: Gran trabajo @ukemi de marcar las preguntas de Medicina con [tag:vocabulario-técnico]. Nótese que en este caso no sé si hace falta, pues _triage_ se usa en muchos otros ámbitos, [incluso en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece ser que en español se usa el término `triaje`, aunque no está recogido en el diccionario de la RAE (Aunque [Triar](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=tri%E9is) sí, con el significado de "Escoger, separar, entresacar").

Parece ser que el término se ha incorporado al vocabulario técnico [del francés](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/328785022809169921) con el significado de

> Clasificación de pacientes que establece el orden de atención.

Al ser un extranjerismo parece ser que también hay bastante confusión acerca de [cómo escribirlo](http://www.e-mergencia.com/foro/f153/triage-triaje-11647/), pero en ese mismo enlace se explica sobre el término:

> El término TRIAJE no ha sido de momento admitido por la Academia. Tampoco aparece en otros diccionarios de uso que hemos consultado. En realidad, por lo textos de la documentación encontrados, parace equivaler a SELECCIÓN o CLASIFICACIÓN. Hemos localizado su empleo en el ámbito hospitalario, haciendo referencia a la clasificación de los enfermos del servicio de urgencias, de forma que sean atendidos según la gravedad de su caso y con independencia del orden de llegada se establezcan los tiempos de espera razonables para cada uno de ellos. También se emplea en la clasificación industrial de residuos, donde se habla de ciertas instalaciones denominadas "plantas de triaje". **Las palabras españolas terminadas en -aje se escriben con jota**.

(En Wikipedia, por ejemplo, lo encontrarás escrito ["triaje"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triaje)).

Comment: No sé del término en francés, pero en inglés triage ya tiene otra denotación más de *rápidamente mejorar lo peor e ir mejorando de eso a lo menos peor* en vez meramente *discriminar según urgencia*

Comment: @guifa, no conocía ese significado (o inflexión) de la palabra.

Comment: Es esa acepción exclusiva del [mundo del Software](http://kfaday.blogspot.com/2008/06/administrando-tareas-y-defectos.html)? Relacionado con metodologías ágiles para evaluar bugs, descartar lo que no entra en una iteración o no es factible, prioritizar tareas y mejorar progresivamente un prototipo?

Comment: Un apunte posterior: en la última edición del diccionario, de 2014 (en línea desde 2015) ya aparece la palabra *triaje* con el significado esperable (acción y efecto de triar).

Comment: ¡Ya existe [_triaje_](https://dle.rae.es/?w=triaje) en el DLE!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' desgraciadamente este término se ha vuelto popular recientemente debido a [la covid-19](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34413/5481)

Comment: sí, aunque en los hospitales ya se venía usando (recuerdo haberlo oído en uno hace un año, aprox, por ejemplo). En algún momento reciente el DLE lo añadió

Answer (score 3):

*Triage* podría traducirse muy fácilmente al español como "valoración", en el sentido clínico: se valora el estado del paciente para determinar su grado de gravedad y ponerlo en la fila de atención. La "valoración" en este sentido es un término ampliamente usado en todos los establecimientos de salud, por lo menos en Colombia.

Comment: Bienvenida. Buena respuesta

Answer (score 2):

No conocía el término pero después de leer las otras respuestas te puedo sugerir **priorización**, que si bien no sale en el diccionario, es un derivado bien formado de

> **[priorizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UCg5Lpp)**
>
> **1**. tr. Dar prioridad a algo.
>
> **[prioridad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UCd7HKS)**
>
> **1**. f. Anterioridad de algo respecto de otra cosa, en tiempo o en orden.
>
> **2**. f. Anterioridad o precedencia de algo respecto de otra cosa que depende o procede de ello.

No significa exactamente lo mismo que triaje, pero sirve como sinónimo contextual, ya que se refiere al orden en se va a realizar algo.

Y por otro lado, de una forma más general puedes usar las siguientes, que tampoco son exactamente lo mismo pero incluyen la idea de separar o escoger:

> **[cribaje](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BG8vlbe)**
>
> **1**. m. *Med*. Acción y efecto de cribar (‖ realizar un examen médico).
>
> **[cribar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BG9GEll)**
>
> Del lat. *cribrāre*.
>
> **2**. tr. Someter a una selección rigurosa un conjunto de personas o cosas.
>
> **3**. tr. *Med*. Realizar un examen médico a un conjunto de personas para detectar una determinada enfermedad y descartar otras.

Answer (score 1):

Se usa la palabra *triage* con frecuencia en francés, portugués, inglés y español, conservando algunos elementos (sobretodo sonoros) de su origen francesa. Por eso, hay confusión sobre su forma escrita.

El diccionario de la RAE describe el buen uso de términos de cualquier origen. Por ejemplo: "ordenador" en España tiene el mismo significado que "computador" en las Américas. Por llamar "ordenador" de "regionalismo", el diccionario de la RAE nos aconseja que esa palabra puede ser mal comprendida fuera de su contexto geográfico.

Ese abordaje me parece útil: podemos usar palabras de orígen extranjera, pero el †érmino tiene que cumplir algunos requisitos básicos del buen uso:

- la palabra tiene que ser fácilmente comprendida por tus lectores
- el término no puede provocar confusión o llamar atención por ser una palabra de uso raro (a no ser que ese sea tu objetivo)
- el uso debe conservar elementos esenciales del significado (p.e., "triaje" tiene que ver con un proceso que determina prioridad, no es sinónimo de "escoger")