# Se hizo una prueba y dio positivo ¿en COVID? ¿por COVID? ¿a COVID? ¿de COVID?

Tags: preposiciones

En estos tiempos de pandemia, es lamentablemente cada vez más común leer artículos sobre personajes famosos que han dado positivo en una u otra prueba de COVID-19. Sin embargo, parece que los periódicos no pueden llegar a un consenso con respecto a la forma apropiada de referirse a este fenomeno.

Según Infobae, un periódico argentino:

> [Trump: Giuliani está "muy bien" tras dar positivo a COVID](https://www.infobae.com/america/agencias/2020/12/08/trump-giuliani-esta-muy-bien-tras-dar-positivo-a-covid/)

Telemundo, una emisora estadounidense, también parece ser partidaria de la preposicion "a":

> [Madre relata pesadilla al dar positivo a COVID-19 junto a su bebé tras
> dar a luz](https://www.telemundo20.com/noticias/local/madre-relata-pesadilla-al-dar-a-luz-y-dar-positivo-a-covid-19-junto-a-su-bebe/2074204/)

O quizás no:

> [Mujer alega que fue despedida injustamente por dar positivo de
> COVID-19](https://www.telemundo52.com/noticias/local/mujer-alega-que-fue-despedida-injustamente-por-dar-positivo-de-covid-19/2134154/)

En Honduras, al menos un periódico también se decanta por "de":

> [Sor María Rosa Leggol recibe tratamiento tras dar positiva de COVID-19](https://proceso.hn/sor-maria-rosa-leggol-recibe-tratamiento-tras-dar-positiva-de-covid-19/)

Tanto en España como en Ecuador, hay algunas personas que optan por "en":

> [Muere una niña de cinco años 15 horas después de dar positivo en
> Covid](https://www.elmundo.es/internacional/2020/11/10/5faa661421efa020198b462e.html)
>
> [¿Sabe qué diferencia hay entre dar positivo en COVID-19 o tener
> anticuerpos de este virus?](https://www.eluniverso.com/noticias/2020/05/14/nota/7840929/sabe-que-diferencia-hay-dar-positivo-covid-19-o-tener-anticuerpos)

Finalmente, algunos artículos incluso usan "por". Me suena a un anglicismo, especialmente porque principalmente aparece en periodicos estadounidenses, pero no estoy seguro, porque se ve en sitios como Bolavip:

> Jesús Corona confirma que se perdió la semifinal de vuelta con Cruz
> Azul tras dar positivo por covid-19

¿Son todas estas formas idiomáticas en alguna zona hispanohablante? ¿En cuáles? ¿Algunos no gozan de la aprobación de la RAE?

Comment: Por cierto, como es de esperar, algunas personas dan positivo [con COVID](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.elnacional.com/deportes/maradona-le-dio-animos-a-gatti-tras-dar-positivo-con-covid-19/amp/o) o hasta [para COVID.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.infobae.com/america/colombia/2020/10/29/juan-sebastian-cabal-vuelve-a-dar-positivo-para-covid-y-peligra-la-clasificacion-al-torneo-de-maestros/%3foutputType=amp-type).

Comment: Relacionado: [Dado que COVID-19 es la enfermedad, ¿sería más correcto decir “la COVID-19”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34413/5481)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/positivo-por-de/#:%7E:text=dar%20positivo%20en%2C%20pero%20tambi%C3%A9n%20dar%20positivo%20por&text=Cuando%20se%20realiza%20una%20prueba,corpus%20l%C3%A9xicos%20de%20la%20Academia.), se puede usar "en", "por" o "para":

> La expresión *dar positivo **en** algo* es la preferible para indicar que se
> ha detectado una sustancia o un organismo en un control, aunque
> también es adecuado *dar positivo **por** algo*.
>
> En los medios de comunicación pueden encontrarse frases con cualquiera
> de las dos preposiciones: «Trump y Melania dan positivo en coronavirus
> a un mes de las elecciones presidenciales», «El jefe de prensa de
> Bolsonaro da positivo en coronavirus» o «Estos son los deportistas de
> élite que han dado positivo por coronavirus».
>
> Cuando se realiza una prueba para determinar si una persona ha
> consumido una sustancia o está infectada por algún patógeno, la forma
> más asentada es *dar positivo en (alcohol, cocaína, coronavirus…)*, tal
> como se aprecia en los corpus léxicos de la Academia. No obstante,
> también es posible optar por *dar positivo por* si a continuación se
> especifica la causa de dicho resultado o si se interpreta que se está
> omitiendo el sustantivo *presencia*: *dar positivo por (la presencia de)
> coronavirus*.
>
> No resulta adecuado, en cambio, emplear la preposición de, por lo que
> en «su nombre dio la vuelta al mundo por ser el primer jugador de la
> NBA en dar positivo de coronavirus», lo recomendable habría sido
> escribir positivo en coronavirus o por ser el primer caso positivo de
> coronavirus en la NBA, donde de introduce el complemento del
> sustantivo caso.
>
> Si la persona no está infectada o no ha consumido la sustancia, lo
> adecuado es *dar negativo en (coronavirus, alcohol, cocaína…)*.
>
> En el español americano también se emplea, incluso en registros
> cultos, la variante *dar positivo **para***, traducción del anglicismo *to
> test positive for*.
>
> Así pues, los tres ejemplos iniciales son adecuados.

La preposición "con" funciona cuando introduce la enfermedad en frases como "estar con COVID" y no guarda relación con "dar positivo/negativo". La frase "dar positivo/negativo con COVID" pareciera indicar "dar positivo/negativo en/por/para X enfermedad/sustancia teniendo (además) COVID" o ser el resultado de la síntesis de estas dos frases verbales: "dio positivo: está con COVID".

La preposición "a" parece introducir el elidido "la prueba de": dio positivo a la prueba de COVID. Si la frase "la prueba de" está ausente, se quiebra la cadena semántica.